# Angular : Form with FormGroup with a ngFor. How to collect data?

Tags: angular

I want to do a form to choose to predict several tennis game between player 1 and player 2.

I put an NgFor to display my games and I have a formControlName="predictionUser_{{index}}" for each game.

My problem is I don't know how to get my data from this form."predictionUser_{{index}} is not going to match with the predictionUser of my onSavePrediction method ?

Moreover Do you have any idea of how could I put a link between this prediction and the match Id ?

You can see my html code below and my onSavePrediction() method:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="predictionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSavePrediction()">
      <h2>The games</h2>
      <div class="list-group"
          class="list-group-item"
          *ngFor="let index = index; let match of matches | keyvalue async">
      <h3> Day {{match.value.Day}}</h3>
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ match.value.player1 }} - {{ match.value.player2 }}</h4>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"  id="inlineRadio1" value="1" formControlName="predictionPlayer_{{index}}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="2" formControlName="predictionPlayer_{{index}}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <p></p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="predictionForm.invalid"
                type="submit">Enregistrer
        </button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  onSavePrediction(){
    const idUser="init";
    const predictionUser = this.predictionForm.get('predictionUser').value;
    const idMatch="init";

    const newPrediction = new Prediction(idPlayer,predictionUser,idMatch);

    this.predictionService.createNewPrediction(newPrediction);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use the `FormGroup` data inside the `onSavePrediction` method?
It's not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve with the `onSavePrediction` method. I would use the match id in your form instead of an index.

```
  onSavePrediction(){
    const idUser="init";
    const predictionUser = this.predictionForm.get('predictionUser').value;
    const idMatch="init";

    // do something with the data here?
    // what is the value of the formdata here? is it of the form ~={predictionPlayer_0 : value, predictionPlayer_1: value}
    const formdata = this.predictionForm.value; 


    const newPrediction = new Prediction(idPlayer,predictionUser,idMatch);

    this.predictionService.createNewPrediction(newPrediction);
  }
```

I would think you want the formControlName to be related to your match, and the value related to the player.

e.g.

```
<div class="list-group"
          class="list-group-item"
          *ngFor="let index = index; let match of matches | keyvalue async">
      <h3> Day {{match.value.Day}}</h3>
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ match.value.player1 }} - {{ match.value.player2 }}</h4>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"  id="inlineRadio1" [ngValue]="match.value.player1" formControlName="match.value.id">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{match.value.player1}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" [ngValue]="match.value.player2" formControlName="match.value.id">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">{{match.value.player2}}</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: The onSavePrediction method is used to push my data inside the database. I have a table Prediction and the data are : the prediction, the id of the match and the id of the user. Could you tell me more about the things you put in comment ? I'm sure you get the point :) but I don't know what to do with this and what is the name of this trick ? (if the syntax you used have a meaning and if I want to document me to have a better understanding). Thanks

Comment: yes it is ! for each game it's going to be predictionPlayer_0, predictionPlayer_1 and so on . And the main idea is to make it match with my predictionPlayer of my object Prediction to be able to push each prediction in my database with the id of the player and the id of  the match.